# How to disable Visual Studio's intellisense when using lambda expressions in Razor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, intellisense

When in a Razor .cshtml file, I want to create the line:

```
@this.Html.LabelFor( x => x.Name )
```

However, after typing the first 'x', Visual Studio's intellisense attempts to auto-complete this for me.

Is there a way to disable the autoselect when a lambda expression may be typed, as it does in standard .cs files?

I don't want to untick the "Committed by pressing the space bar" option in the Tools/Text Editor/C#/IntelliSense menu.

Comment: Do you have an `x` declared somewhere? If not what does auto-complete show?

Comment: out of curiosity, why not just @Html.LabelFor(...)?

Comment: Not really an answer but I just hit escape to cancel the auto-complete box when needed.  I don't know of a way to do what you ask though.

Comment: It's a bug in the parser - in some installations it causes an exception

Comment: thanks for your help - will just press escape I think - in code I generally prefix anything that can by "this" as I think it helps readability - I can see your point that it isn't as applicable in a view file though

Comment: Prefixing members with `this` makes sense when you want to *highlight the fact you are referring to a member*. Following the rule blindly and putting `this` everywhere possible leads to bloated and stupid code, which is true for any coding convention. There is a certain idea in calling a property `Html`, and this idea is simplicity. It's not called `GetHtmlHelper` because ASP .NET MVC tries to *bring some sugarness to the code while still using C# syntax*. Much like anonymous types used as dictionaries. You are ruining the idea (and recognizable pattern!) by using `this` here. It's ugly.

Answer (score 3):

There don't seem to be any options to specifically control intellisense in Razor, in lambdas. However, you could turn on "low impact intellisense" by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Space when you're typing one (and the same to turn it off). This will stop the intellisense automatically select things (you have to manually pick them). Sure, it's a pain to turn on/off all the time, but it might be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In search of an answer I found this page. Once I found one, I thought I would post back, in case others are looking.

Now, it is usually located in the "Options" screen, under the advanced section of that language. Others are similar, here is a snip of the C# advanced section: [A block named Inline Hints will have a section that typically shows something akin to "...show lambda parameter type."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP2m1.png)